# Authenticate and login users and opening new page

Tags: django

i have two pages in my Django website: home page and the chatting page!

What i want is when the users clicks "start-chatting" app should Authenticate using the user name then do the login after that open the chatting page.

my files:

***home.js:***

```
$('.btn-xl').click(function(){
var uname = ('.message-input').val();
$.ajax({
    url : '/LogIIn/',
    type : 'POST',
    data : { name: uname },});
 window.open('http://gadgetron.store/P_chat'); 
 $('.message-input').val(null);
 document.getElementById('radio02').checked=false;
 document.getElementById('radio01').checked=false;
});
```

***views.py:***

```
from chatbot import settings
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login



@csrf_exempt 
def P_home(request):
   context= locals()
   template= 'P_home.html'
   return render(request,template,context)

@csrf_exempt 
def P_chat(request):
    context= locals()
    template= 'P_chat.html'
    return render(request,template,context)

@csrf_exempt 
def LogIIn(request):
   name = request.POST.get('name')
   password = '!Emoo1989'
   user = authenticate(username=name)
   login(request, user) 
   return HttpResponse("OK")
```

i'm new in the authentication but the code didn't work with me

Comment: Is the user already created in the DB? And, you have to provide `password` as a `kwarg` to the method `authenticate` for authenticating the user, provided the user exists in DB with those credentials.

Comment: @SachinKukreja yes i'm sure that the user in created and saved in the DB, and also what do you mean by kwarg ?

Comment: kwarg = keyword argument, like you have provided `username` to `authenticate`, you need `password` as well in the argument list.